# Selenium Python to open all Facebook posts in a group using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, automation

I'm trying to go on a Facebook group and go through the first 20 posts. Normally there are keyboard shortcuts that Facebook has to help navigate through the posts. One is the "j" key where it goes from post to post. The next one is the "ENTER" key where it expands the post if it is too long (like clicking "see more". Normally if I just spam "j" + ENTER repeatedly, it will go through all the posts and expand them if they can. I have the following Selenium Python code to execute such a behavior:

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    time.sleep(1)
    element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN + "j" + Keys.ENTER)
    i += 1
```

It will go to all the posts and it only expands the first possible "see more" but doesn't expand anything else. How would I design this code?

For anyone who's wondering about the `Keys.ARROW_DOWN`, its found in another stackoverflow question:  [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902295/how-to-send-shortcut-keys-using-selenium-in-python-to-move-through-webpage)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight mistake in your code. Your code finds body element each time inside the loop so on each iterate it will find 'body' element and perform the send keys function on the first element on every iteration.

Your code should be modified to :

```
i = 0
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
while i < 20:
    time.sleep(1)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN + "j" + Keys.ENTER)
    i += 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried that as well and still no difference in behavior. Thanks anyways!